# How to execute a script javascript dynamically created with JSDOM in a jest test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

I have a module that provides some convenience functions for DOM manipulation that I'm trying to test with Jest and jsdom, but I seem to be doing something wrong in instantiating it.

The expect test within `dom.window.document.addeventlistener ('domcontentloaded'...` is not passing, the console.log I added inside `../mocks/forTesting.js` also does not appear when running the test.

> Does anyone have any idea how to make this test work? I need the script to run and the div with id="container" change to 'test'

Here is the test code.

```
import { runScript } from '../export/script.js';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id="container">Hello</div></body></html>`, { resources: 'usable',  runScripts: "dangerously" })
global.window = dom.window
global.document = dom.window.document

describe("Rendering Module", () => {
   test("Verify if mocked script was executed", async () => {
        const script = { name: 'testScript', value: `<script src="../mocks/forTesting.js" ></script>` }
        const scriptFreezed = Object.freeze(script);
        await runScript(scriptFreezed, dom.window.document);
    
        dom.window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const text = dom.window.document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
            expect(text).toEqual('test')
        });

        dom.window.document.dispatchEvent(new dom.window.Event('DOMContentLoaded', {"bubbles": true}))
    })
})
```

The test is giving success as it was passing but is giving this error when running

```
console.error
    Error: Uncaught [Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "test"
    Received: "Hello"
```

Here is the code in ../mocks/forTesting.js.

```
window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log('forTesting.js')
    window.document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'test';
});
```

Here is the runScript code.

```
const runScript = (script, dom) => {
    const node = dom.createRange().createContextualFragment(script.value);
    dom.head.appendChild(node);
}
```